# Excel VBA saving multiple worksheets from existing code

Tags: excel, vba, save, worksheet

I wasn't able to find a specific answer before posting.

Could someone assist in tweaking my existing VBA code in Excel that would enable me to copy 2 sheets, and not just 1? I am getting an error. It works with 1 sheet, but not 2. I have put the code in bold where it is failing.

```
Sub Export()

Dim FlSv As Variant
Dim MyFile As String
Dim MyTemplate As String
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim wbNew As Workbook

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With
```

**This is where it fails:**

```
Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 1", "Sheet 2")
    sh.Copy

    Set wbNew = ActiveWorkbook

    MyFile = Replace("Consolidated", ".xlsm", "")

    FlSv = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(MyFile, fileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx)", Title:="Enter your file name")

    wbNew.SaveAs FlSv, FileFormat:=51
    wbNew.Close

    For Each s In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If s.Name Like "*Sheet 1*" Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            s.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    Next s

  For Each s In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If s.Name Like "*Sheet 2*" Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            s.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    Next s

    End Sub
```

Tried this too:

```
Sub Export()

Dim FlSv As Variant
Dim MyFile As String
Dim MyTemplate As String
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim wbNew As Workbook

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With

'Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Overrun")
'sh.Copy
'Set wbNew = ActiveWorkbook

ActiveWorkbook.workheets(Array("Sheet 1", "Sheet 2")).Copy
'there is a new activeworkbook with two worksheets
Set wbNew = ActiveWorkbook

MyFile = Replace("Consolidated", ".xlsm", "")

FlSv = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(MyFile, fileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx)", Title:="Enter your file name")

wbNew.SaveAs FlSv, FileFormat:=51
wbNew.Close

For Each s In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If s.Name Like "*Overrun*" Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        s.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
Next s

End Sub
Sub all()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an array of worksheet names.

```
dim wb as workbook

ActiveWorkbook.sheets(array("Sheet 1", "Sheet 2")).copy
'there is a new activeworkbook with two worksheets
set wb = ActiveWorkbook
```

Comment: Says error at the Activeworkbook code:

Object doesnt support this property method

Comment: I'm not spelling well today.

Comment: The error comes from the ActiveWorkbook.worksheets(array("Sheet 1", "Sheet 2")).copy line

Comment: The code works for me as long as I supply valid worksheet names. The ones above come from your original code in your question.

Comment: Not sure what the issue is. I am trying it I have edited the above to show my full code.

Comment: Ahh I think I solved it.

Its ActiveWorkbook.Sheets not worksheets

Comment: Feel free to update your code and I will accept the answer